# Primes (fractions) that cannot be expressed as the sum of two distinct unit fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck on the question:

> Prove that $\frac{p - 1}{p}$, with $p > 5$ and $p$ prime, cannot be expressed as the sum of two distinct unit fractions. (Unit fractions = $\frac{1}{n}$, with $n$ some integer.)

I tried using $$1 - \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$$
and thus $$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{p} = 1.$$

I am stuck here. Can anybody give me a hint on how to approach this kind of question? (Don't need the answer right now.)

Comment: Hint: $p\gt5\implies1-1/p\gt4/5\gt1/3+1/3$.

Comment: @BarryCipra that does not seem obvious to me of how it would help me solve this.

Comment: Note that $p$ must divide $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Can $a$ and $b$ both be large?

Comment: No, it can't. A or B must be equal to 2.

Comment: Nevermind, Barry. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Kapil, why must $p$ divide both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: The largest number, on the one hand, that is less than $1$ that can be written as a sum of $2$ uniform fractions is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{6}$. All numbers of the form $\frac{p-1}{p}$ for $p >5$, on the other hand, are in the interval $[\frac{6}{7},1)$. Can you finish from there.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.

Comment: Sorry. Why does the largest number that is less than 1 and can be written as a sum of two distinct unit fraction become $1/2+1/3=5/6$ instead of $1/n+1/(n+1)=(2n+1)/(n^2+n)$?

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy if you sub n=1, you get 3/2 >1. if you sub n=2, you get 5/6.

Comment: @cineel: Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{p}=1$
$abp=ab+bp+pa$
$p|ab$
WLOG $p|a$
$a\geq p\geq 7$
$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{p}\leq$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint.